# How to open MySQL Workbench ER model in DBeaver

Tags: mysql-workbench, dbeaver

I have made a move from MySQL to MariaDB and the only open source database client/tool is DBeaver. But I have some ER models (.mwb) that I had created in MySql Workbench. I need to know if it is possible at all to somehow import and edit those models in DBeaver.

Comment: No, I did not import - just recreated in DBeaver.

Comment: I also need this. Is there any way found ?